# any website monitoring library/modules to use in my website?

Tags: java, javascript

I'm trying to build a site which user can add their websites which should be monitored and can view a detailed report and statistics of it. And also it should be able to monitor local webservices (mainly),

1) is there any popular java library to use for monitoring a website? (in sense to ping a website and load some content etc., or to show whether site is up or not kinda)

2) Also to validate a flow of website (if possible)?
Example: Go to login page, find fields , fill fields and submit form and validate for successful login or not.

I know this kinda looks big but any small part done can be helpful, I've found several of monitoring projects, but they only do normal websites but not local/other webservices and also they can't validate flow of website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All types of normal monitoring can be done via [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/).

However to test the flow of a website you should probably set up automated test software for production. E.g Run [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) scripts. You may run them with [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) or directly via a cronjob.

I previously answered a similar question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/250243/how-to-setup-monitors-to-check-the-reachability-of-external-servers/250261#250261), referring to a monitoring software I wrote myself once.

Answer (score 1):

@flurdy gave some good suggestions. Nagios is good, Selenium is great.

For graphs, checkout [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)

For site flow check out http://www.dejaclick.com/ - their app uses a Firefox extension to record user interaction on a site then replay it throughout the day to test whether or not it can complete that cycle. So for example, adding something to a shopping cart and checking out completely.